# convert text file to ini file with parameters and values

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

We have the following text file , this is configuration file:

```
advertised.host.name: DEPRECATED: only used when advertised.listeners or listeners are not set. Use advertised.listeners instead. Hostname to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If this is not set, it will use the value for host.name if configured. Otherwise it will use the value returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().

    Type: string
    Default: node1
    Valid Values:
    Importance: high
    Update Mode: read-only

advertised.listeners: Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use, if different than the listeners config property. In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If this is not set, the value for listeners will be used. Unlike listeners it is not valid to advertise the 0.0.0.0 meta-address.

    Type: string
    Default: null
    Valid Values:
    Importance: high
    Update Mode: per-broker

advertised.port: DEPRECATED: only used when advertised.listeners or listeners are not set. Use advertised.listeners instead. The port to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. In IaaS environments, this may need to be different from the port to which the broker binds. If this is not set, it will publish the same port that the broker binds to.

    Type: int
    Default: 5500
    Valid Values:
    Importance: high
    Update Mode: read-only

auto.create.topics.enable: Enable auto creation of topic on the server

    Type: boolean
    Default: true
    Valid Values:
    Importance: high
    Update Mode: read-only

.
.
.
```

What we want is to convert the file above to be ini file as the following

```
advertised.host.name=node1
advertised.listeners=null
advertised.port=5500
auto.create.topics.enable=true
.
.
.
```

note - each parameter in text file is in the beginning of the file without space 
while the value is represented by the *Default* ,

any suggestion how to convert the `text` file to `ini` file with bash or awk or perl/python , etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F': ' '/^[^\t ]+:/{key=$1; next}; $1 ~ /^[\t ]+Default/{print key "=" $2}' file
advertised.host.name=node1
advertised.listeners=null
advertised.port=5500
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

Comment: Freddy you are the best - the best answer that I have seen

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below method and worked fine

```
awk -F ":"  '/advertised|auto.create/{f=$1;print f}/Default/{print $2}' filename| sed "N;s/\n/=/g"
```

output

```
advertised.host.name=node1
advertised.listeners=null
advertised.port=5500
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import itertools
from itertools import islice
final=[]
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    if i.startswith('advertised' or 'auto') or i.startswith('auto'):
        final.append(i.split(":")[0].strip())
        p=list(islice(k,3))
        for z in p:
            if re.search('Default',z):
                final.append(z.split(":")[-1].strip())


for g in range(0, len(final),2):
    print  "=".join(final[g:g+2])
```

output

```
advertised.host.name=node1
advertised.listeners=null
advertised.port=5500
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```